# How do you tell if the last value in a list repeats previously?

Tags: python, list

I.E

```
Value = [1,2,3,4,5,1]
```

How do I tell if that one in the beginning repeats at the end. I figured out a somewhat fool proof way but it does not work when ever I plug in a single value instead of them being next to each other.

```
def last_repeats(list):
  for i in range(1, len(list)):
    if list[i] == list[-1]:
      return True
    else:
      return False
def main():
  last_repeats(list)

############################################
### Don't edit anything below this line. ###
############################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: forgot to add my code...

Comment: Instead of pasting your code as a comment, please [edit] your code into your question :)

Comment: Also, your question is unclear. Do you mean if the first and last values are equal, or if the last value appears in the rest of the list? Please clarify, your example and code are contradictory.

Answer (score 2):

A general way:

```
if Value[-1] in Value[:-1]:
    # ...
```

This proves if the last value appears somewhere earlier in the list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
Value[0] == Value[-1]
```

to check if the first value and the last value are the same

---

> How do you tell if the last value in a list repeats previously?

```
Value[-1] in Value[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Value[-1] to check it denotes the last elements of the list.

```
if Value[0] == Value[-1]:
    #Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

O(1) space and best case O(1) time:

```
>>> it = reversed(Value)
>>> next(it) in it
True
```